# Google play Services out of date in real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I am Building an application in which i have require a GCM to implement, I have implemented that, then after when i am trying run it on my real Devices then it shows me that Google play service out of date and shows dialog that please update Google play service. and I have updated also. but after that i cant ran it on my device please help.

Comment: "i cant ran it on my device": what happened?

Comment: It gives me error that Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3264100 but found 3225134. now what to do?

Comment: Go to google play services https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en and check if it showing update for you.

Comment: @AK Ali: But i have already updated play services. but it is not working.